# Why WINDOW.OPEN function works differently in Chrome as compared to firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window.open

I am using window.open function to open up a new window.But in chrome itopens up with an minimize button and i m able to carry out task in backend window.
However in firefox it works fine ,showing only close button and not allowing me to carry out any operation in backend window.
How can i make my code work in chrome in the same way as it works in firefox.

Comment: Show the code!!! IF you need a modal dialog use showModalDialog instead of window.open or jQuery UI modal dialog

Answer (score 2):

You CANNOT (consistently) using `window.open`. You need to use modal dialogs (as pointed by [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan)) for this.

These kinds of deliberate malicious actions are generally restricted by browsers.

Comment: window.showModalDialog("web/jsp/reminderPopup.jsp?days="+remainingDays,"Booking Update Remarks","dialogWidth:450px;dialogHeight=200px;");

Comment: I have to show the popup using only javascript,jquery is not allowed to use in our application.

Comment: @Nups As I said you cannot using window.open. If you dont want to use jQuery, code the modal by yourself, adding a div then popping it out on the required action and preventing clicks on the rest of the page until the modal is there.